# mysql select record from table except null

Tags: mysql

I have a table name tableA

```
id | name | title    
1   aa  titleaaa    
2   bb  titlebbb    
3   cc  titleccc    
4   aa  titleAAA    
5   dd  null    
6   ee  null    
7   aa  null    
8   bb  null
```

I'm not sure if I can discribe my situation
I want a sql to get the result like below(if 'aa' has multile record, I want all except that title was null, if 'dd' has only one record no matter title is null or not, I want the record ):

```
1   aa  titleaaa
2   bb  titlebbb
3   cc  titleccc
4   aa  titleAAA
5   dd  null
6   ee  null
```

Comment: would be better (faster) to do that in PHP or other... than in query itself...

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If I do that in the php, that work not well with my pager. So I have to do it in sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE TITLE IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE TITLE IS NULL GROUP BY NAME
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE TITLE IS NOT NULL 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE name NOT IN(SELECT NAME FROM TABLENAME WHERE TITLE IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY NAME
```

Try above query.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: If 'aa' has mutiple record (3 or more), I want all record except that title is null.
Your solution miss the one that id is '4'.

Comment: you edit your answer back?
I remember the sql is 'SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE TITLE IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE name NOT IN(SELECT NAME FROM TABLENAME WHERE TITLE IS NOT NULL)  GROUP BY NAME'

Comment: @pdwjun both are same.This one is `optimized`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tableA where title is not null and name not in ('dd') 
union 
select * from tableA where name in ('dd')
```

Suppose you have a list of names like 'dd','ee' etc to ignore the restriction of title being null
Then first part of the query picks all records where title is not null but ignores those without restriction
Second part of query gives all results without any title validations for the selective list as required.

Comment: 'dd' means the record that column name is 'dd'.

Comment: yes it is considering the same, where name in ('dd'), in i have used to give a generalised query in case you have multiple values to handle such case.